# ANOVA for ordinal predictor (in excel only!), and significance of assessing survival *given that an event occurred*

Tags: anova, ordinal-data, excel

I have two predictor variable of interest - one continuous, and one nominal (lipid profile ratio as the continuous, and cardiac hypertrophy type as the nominal).

I also have an outcome of interest - whether a person has had a major adverse cardiac event or not.

I was unable to build a survival curve (unusual circumstances dictate I am only able to use unmodified excel). So for the time being, as I was building some contingency tables to kind of get a feeling for what to expect, what I found out was the following:

[image: These are average times to an event, *given that an event did occur.*]

So my first question is this: for hypertrophy type, ANOVA would work to show that there is a significant difference between the types of hypertrophy on the time to an event. But for the lipid ratios, how do I do an ANOVA that takes into consideration that quartiles are ordinal? I could do linear regression but was curious on how I would apply analysis to this table.

From what I can find, I would use LDA or QDA. But with the unusual stipulation that I can only use Excel, how could I assess significance?

Furthermore, I have a broader question as to what these tables would even mean in general. Is it even of interest to anybody to demonstrate that given an event occurs, a variable has a significant correlation to the time to event? I know the variables have nearly no sensible predictive power as to whether an event occurs (from other analysis), but in the tables above, the relationships are undoubtedly significant.

Just how meaningful is the outcome? What does it suggest, when a variable has no correlation to the outcome, unless (you know that) the outcome occurred already?

Comment: Using unmodified Excel is rather limiting. I would need the actual data to even attempt it, and would have to write code, likely, which seems a painful exercise in such a low level language. Next, it is not exactly clear what you are asking. For example, the class of hypertrophy needs explaining before anything can be done with the data. I would guess that the fastest fix would be to sit down with a statistician and go over your data to formulate a plan to analyze what you need.

Comment: Ah. I will indeed be doing just that (meeting a statistician) in just a week. It's just that I'm an undergrad in a non-math field. I didn't want to look like an idiot in front of him and my PI, to be honest, and I wanted to have something interesting to present to them despite the data not showing anything particularly interesting (with respect to the specific stated aims of the project).

Comment: The last question is still of interest to me though. What does it mean when a variable is only associated with a time to event, if the event occurred?

Comment: Well, it is philosophical. It doesn't mean anything to those whose event has already occurred, but, it might mean something prospectively for those whose event has not occurred but find themselves in a similar situation to the starting situation of your patients.

Comment: Also, correlation is not 'causation' and it matters what correlations are attempted and how they are attempted. Let me put it this way, a lack of a significant correlation does not necessarily mean anything, but it might mean something.